Does God experience any emotion other than love?
Does the Christian God experience any other emotion than the love of his creation and its creatures?
If God experienced anger, for example, would that be a character flaw?

Love is not an 'emotion'. Emotion (noun) instinctive feeling as distinguished from reasoning or knowledge. Oxford English Dictionary. I think you may be assuming that 'love' is a form of natural affection. Which is not appropriate to Deity.

Short answer is YES.  When theorizing God's emotional life we can only do so by analogy with our own range of emotions.  God creates our human nature, so God can always potentially be more than us.  In Star Trek, the cybernetic engineer Dr. Noonien Soong who creates the human android Data is richer (emotionally) than Data.
In Thomistic scheme, anger is a neutral passion that can be directed either for bad or for good.  Anger that protects is good, anger that destroys is better worded in English to wrath or rage, a sin.
In the Bible, God's anger is directed toward sin, or toward people who oppressed the righteous weak.  In this case, it's a good anger, and thus not a character flaw, but consistent with a healthy anger.  If a father is not angry when his child is abused, then he is not a good father.

The God of the Bible is spoken of in theological terms as having some "Incommunicable Attributes", and his attributes are identical with his being.Although God has revealed this to an extent in his written word, and in his dealings with humanity, they are beyond mortal ability to grasp e.g. Eternity (his transcendence of time); Aseity (self-existence); Immutability (unchangeableness); Impassibiity (incapacity for being overwhelmed by suffering).
Then there are his "Communicable Attributes", such as his righteousness, goodness, love, knowledge, and wisdom. These are shared analogically with human beings as his image-bearers. But we can never afford to forget that (since Adam rebelled against God) that image is marred. Sin has corrupted the entire human race, so that our feelings are base, compared with God's perfection of attributes. For us to try to equate our feelings with God's feelings, or to compare them that way, is an exercise in futility, if not gross disrespect to God.
Only once we have understood the chasm that divides the holy God from unholy humanity, can we begin to adjust our thinking about God. Until we do, we will forever look at matters from our point of view, which is mortal, sinful, and immensely ignorant compared with God's immortal, pure and all-knowing stance.
So, the answer to the question is, yes, God created many emotions that were pure and perfect, to endow the first human couple with. How could he do that without having such emotions himself? Yet none of the originally perfect emotions he created in humanity at the start have remained intact, for sin has greatly corrupted them all. There was no need for anger when everything was sinless and perfect, if you think about it.
Think also about the attribute of love. Most humans have no idea that there are four types of love, and that it is the highest form that God has. The Greek word for that is agape. It is principled love that seeks the good of the other, irrespective of the other deserving that love or not. That is the highest standard of love Christians are called to emulate. That is what Jesus showed when going to the cross for God to deal righteously with sin. And you may be sure God has anger towards sin. But it is righteous anger, and not many people on earth have much idea about that. This would make it counter-productive for them to try to think of God's anger as a "character flaw" as it would only prove they had no idea about God's anger being righteous, never out of balance with that, or with his love and willingness to forgive.
I hope those points assist you begin to get to grips with this matter.

"Incommunicable Attributes" - I've learned something new today and it's not even 7 a.m.


"Anger": a strong feeling of annoyance, displeasure, or hostility.
"Hostility": unfriendliness or opposition.
"Hatred": intense dislike or ill will.

"Anger" is very different from "hatred".
It's perfectly normal for parents to experience anger as a result of their children's behaviour, without any lessening of "love".
In fact, that anger might even be the result of love.
One can easily ignore or dismiss the behaviour of strangers, but not that of one's own family.
If someone does something that you don't like, why would it be a character flaw for you to experience anger?
Rather, it would be a flaw if you didn't care about the behaviour of those that you love.

So man and God are equal emotionally? Are there any other characteristics of Man that are equitable to God? Is God's image, that is reflected in man , a physical image, a mental image, both or neither?

@8Mad0Manc8 asks "So man and God are equal emotionally?" — "Equal" no; "Equivalent" yes. Man's purpose is to develop character approaching that of the Father, as demonstrated in human form by the Son. ¶ Compare with the human relationship: Genesis 1:26, "God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness", and 5:3, "[Adam] begat a son in his own likeness, after his image".

I find  it unlikely that once God had created Man then Man could create a descendant in any other form than that of itself? Howver Iam equally not convinced that God would choose a Form that was dissimilar to his own? Thanks for your comment

@8Mad0Manc8 Now I am interested to understand how you found it unlikely that God would not create a being that can reproduce. But to make the idea more approachable: In Christianity, people believe that God is omnipotent. Meaning that he could do everything. So making a being like a human that reproduces seems to be in the realm of the possible. Regarding the Form: Well the problem is a bit that God is beyond the physical, so he could choose to take any form he likes. He did manifest as a human multiple times, even when ignoring Jesus' case.

@8Mad0Manc8 regarding the similarities/differences between God and Man: The main differences are: God is physically unlimited, created the whole world including humans, is omnipotent and omnipresent, meaning he is everywhere and thus beyond time and space. Humans on the other hand have a limited physical body, limited cognitive capabilities, and limited capabilities in general. But the similarities include self-awareness, creativity, morality, etc. but all in limited capacity compared to God. The description of "Image" is quite accurate, as like a mirror is similar to you its also different.

@telion, the mirror analogy is very apt, as it exists in only two dimensions. Your missing third dimension couldn't ever be comprehended by a a two dimensional mirror being.

Sure, the other emotion mentioned in the Bible is Jealousy. He is a jealous God and hates it when we divert more of our attention to worldly things than to him.
Exodus 34:14

You must worship no other gods, for the LORD, whose very name is Jealous, is a God who is jealous about his relationship with you

From this, we can deduce that God is capable of any other human emotion. To answer your question, Yes God is capable of other emotions apart from love
